# Invalid Decimal Literal on Currency Conversion Script

Tags: python

Had a general question regarding Invalid Decimal Literal.

I've created a basic currency conversion script for ad spends on pivot tables that use USD and I'm converting it to GBP.

I've gone over the script and have tried to optimise by using online resources and using Stack Overflow. I've experimented with several solutions but I can't seem to figure out nor understand why it's happening and how to apply best practice from making ridiculous mistakes.

I've attached the code below for your review:

```
import requests
  
class Currency_convertor:
    # empty dict to store the conversion rates
    rates = {} 
    def __init__(self, url):
        data = requests.get(url).json()
  
        # Extracting only the rates from the json data
        self.rates = data["rates"] 
  

    # function to do a simple cross multiplication between 
    # the amount and the conversion rates
    def convert(self, from_currency, to_currency, amount):
        initial_amount = amount
        if from_currency != 'EUR' :
            amount = amount / self.rates[from_currency]
  
        # limiting the precision to 2 decimal places
        amount = round(amount * self.rates[to_currency], 2)
        print('{} {} = {} {}'.format(initial_amount, from_currency, amount, to_currency))
  
***# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = str.__add__('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=', 95e8617f265030569da10ad979de7ed4)**  
    c = Currency_convertor(url)
    from_country = input("From Country: ")
    to_country = input("TO Country: ")
    amount = int(input("Amount: ")))*
  
    c.convert(from_country, to_country, amount)
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

**It's been mentioned in the comments that I wasn't clear the part of the Driver code were it's causing a Syntax Error with Invalid Decimal Literal has been fixed but it has been replaced with another error: TypeError: expected 1 argument, got 0.**

Comment: What's that invalid literal?

Comment: I read the question 2 times and still don't know what the issue is that you are asking about.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. You should ask a *clear and specific question* - one which arises after your own [best effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [diagnose the problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), which starts by trying to *read and understand* the error message you're getting. At the very least, you should [show it, completely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) when asking.

Comment: The SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal on line 26.

Comment: I've managed to solve the Syntax Error and it has been replaced with another error: TypeError: expected 1 argument, got 0

Comment: Please try to follow a tutorial for Python so that you understand what the most common error messages mean.

Comment: Keep in mind that we don't have your error logs or line numbers here...

Comment: Also, you should probably re-generate your API key, and do not post it publicly in the future.

Comment: Decimal literals don't have hexadecimal numbers in them.  The error is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your driver code has two very basic errors:

1. Your access key (which is a string) is missing quotes around it.  Python is trying to interpret it as a number, which is why you get the "invalid decimal" error.  Just put quotes around it (better yet, skip the whole `str.__add__` thing and just hardcode the whole string since it's a constant anyway).
2. You have an errant `)` on one of your `input` lines.

Fixed code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=95e8617f265030569da10ad979de7ed4'
    c = Currency_convertor(url)
    from_country = input("From Country: ")
    to_country = input("TO Country: ")
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
  
    c.convert(from_country, to_country, amount)
```

If you want to separate the access key from the rest of the url, I'd suggest using an f-string.  F-strings would also simplify the formatting/rounding you're doing in your `convert` function:

```
import requests


class CurrencyConverter:
    def __init__(self, access_key):
        # Extract the rates from the json data
        self.rates = requests.get(
            f'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={access_key}'
        ).json()["rates"]

    def convert(self, from_currency, to_currency, amount):
        """Cross multiply the amount and the conversion rates, print result."""
        result = amount * self.rates[to_currency] / self.rates[from_currency]
        # Round to 2 decimal places.
        print(f"{amount} {from_currency} = {result:.2f} {to_currency}")
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CurrencyConverter('95e8617f265030569da10ad979de7ed4')
    from_country = input("From Country: ")
    to_country = input("To Country: ")
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
  
    c.convert(from_country, to_country, amount)
```

```
From Country: USD
To Country: GBP
Amount: 100
100 USD = 73.88 GBP
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifing where I went wrong, i;ve been staring at the screen for hours didn't realise there would multiple mistakes.

Couple of general questions to learn from this episode:

1. For the access key is it best practice to use single quotes or double quotes?

2. I've read online that there is a string to int conversion in python is that not recommended all the time?

3. The str.__add__ that should be used in certain circumstances or is hardcoding more apt?

4. I didn't see the missing ) thanks for checking that out.

Comment: 1. Doesn't matter.  2. Do it when it makes sense to, don't do it when it doesn't.  3. If you can easily express something as a single string, just do that instead of trying to make it more complicated.  If you do have two strings you need to combine, you should use `+` instead of `str.__add__`.  See also f-strings which are useful when you're combining a bunch of things into one string.

Comment: Thank you for you comments its been helpful to learn.